# Using hook_node_submit() from a custom module

Tags: hooks, nodes

I have built a custom module named 'ABC'. I have created a content type 'CT' having some text fields. When a user add content of type 'CT' and Save/Preview the form, I want to use the values that the user added in the form and make a web service call and update the form values based on the data returned from the web service call which would further be saved to database.

I am using `hook_node_submit()` as below.

```
function CT_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  //dpm($user);
  $nameofuser = $user->name;
  $timezone = $user->timezone;
  $title = $form['field_title']['#value'];
  $pid = $user->uid;
  $pname = $user->name;
  $rurl = $form['field_recording_url']['#value'];
  $purl = $form['field_presenter_url']['#value'];

  $kdetails  = array (
     'nameofuser' => $nameofuser,
'title' => $title,
'pid' => $pid,
'pname' => $pname,
  );
  Make_A_WebService_Call($kdetails, $form, $form_state);
}
```

The problem is that when I am calling the above code from ABC.module file, the code is not being called on clicking the Save/Preview button.

Answer (score 2):

[`hook_node_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) will only be invoked for the module implementing the associated content type. If module A defines the content type, module B cannot implement `hook_node_submit()` on module A's behalf, unless it specifically calls the function `module_B_node_submit()`.

If you want to hook into the validation process of a node form you can use the standard [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7), e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_node_form_validate';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_node_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Logic here...
}
```

Comment: So, Can I use CT_ABC_Node_Submit() as suggested by you ?

Comment: No, you need to use `hook_form_alter()` (see the answer above). Oh wait, is the name `MYMODULE_node_form_validate` causing confusion? That's just a randomly named function, the name has no significance in terms of hooks/being automatically called or anything like that. You can substitute that for whatever you want, as long as you update the string reference to it in the form alter

Comment: @AnubhavSharma MYMODULE is just a generic replacement for the module short name; if your module is my_nice_module.module, then replace MYMODULE with my_nice_module.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you are saying that in the ABC.module you are implemented the CT content type, and you are wondering why `ABC_node_submit()` (the implementation of [hook_node_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7)) is not being invoked.

If `ABC_node_submit()` is a function contained in ABC.module, then it will be invoked only in the case, the implementation of [hook_node_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7) is similar to the following one.

```
function abc_node_info() {
  return array(
    'ct' => array(
      'name' => t('the content type name'),
      'base' => 'ct',
      'description' => t('the content type description'),
    ),
  );
}
```

(I use lowercase letters since it is preferable that the short name of a module uses only lowercase letters.)

In this case, when invoking `hook_node_submit()` for that content type, Drupal will look for `abc_node_submit()`.

In fact, in the documentation for `hook_node_info()`, `base` is described as follows:

> The base string used to construct callbacks corresponding to this node type (for example, if base is defined as example_foo, then `example_foo_insert()` will be called when inserting a node of that type). This string is usually the name of the module, but not always.

This answer is valid if `ABC_node_submit()` is a function contained in the ABC.module. If you have two modules (ABC.module and CT.module) where ABC.module is implementing the content type, and CT.module is another module that needs to add a form validation or a form submission handler to the form used to edit a node of that content type, then see [Clive's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/83918/199).